# Converting from RAID 1 to RAID 0

Tags: linux, raid, hardware, storage, hardware-raid

We have 2 x 600GB SAS 15K drives configured in RAID 1 through a PERC H710 RAID controller in a PowerEdge R620. Question. Can we convert this to RAID 0 without having need for a OS reinstall? If so, what are the normal steps?

(yes, we know that it is at the cost of redundancy, but we have need for storage space and redundancy is not at all needed. Part of a large cluster running analytics. One or a few nodes / disks failing here and there is completely tolerable. Reason behind this question is more SLA related. Running a change without an impact on SLA for several nodes).

Comment: Similar to this [removing-raid-on-a-dell-power-edge-server](http://serverfault.com/questions/241616/removing-raid-on-a-dell-power-edge-server).
Make sure you have a backup if you decide to try and break the RAID1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [this is possible](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN156106/EN).

I don't like the reasoning for it, since you're likely better off acquiring more disks. However, an online or offline virtual disk reconfiguration is definitely possible with your controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Moving linux system from one raid mode to another is possible, but quite complicated:

1. You need full backup of the file system preserving permissions (`tar`), some live cd for example.
2. Changing mode of the array part.
3. Creating partition/lvm and restoring it from backup (again with preserving permissions) (`parted`).
4. Making adjustments in grub/lilo configuration files and fstab.
5. Rebuilding boot sector/boot manager in chroot mode (`grub-install`/`lilo`).
6. Rebuilding initrd may also be necessary (`mkinitrd`).